# Rails how to make a number (3) to a variable (three)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create some javascript links.

I need to transform the ID of a object to a variable.

For example:

```
Company.id = 3
```

I want to transform the ID to a variable like three in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use the functionality provided by the Ruby Linguistics Project:

[English - Ruby Linguistics](http://deveiate.org/projects/Linguistics/wiki/English)

```
companyLinkValue = Company.id.en.numwords
```

Comment: I have that problem it is generating this: twenty-threes which is not a variable, because of the "-" Are there a way to remove the "-"

Comment: @Beginner - I'm going to go out on a limb and guess you need to use the gsub method: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186